# emit signal to specific thread in qt

Tags: multithreading, qt, signals

i want to emit sendData signal to specific thread. ex. 5th thread.
but when i call emit with sendData(), it calls recvData of all connected thread.
how can i fix this issue?

```
QList<QThread*> threads;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {

    QTH* thread = new QTH(i);
    connect( this, SIGNAL(sendData(int)), thread, SLOT(recvData(int)) );
    threads.append(thread);
    thread->start();
}

//i want to emit to only 5th thread.
emit sendData(10);
```

Comment: If you only want the emitted signal to be processed by the N'th thread then only call `connect` if `i == N` -- but that's almost certainly *not* what you really want.  As shown this looks like an [xy-problem](https://xyproblem.info/) so you should probably provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the underlying issue you're trying to solve.

Comment: ... esp. since in the code above all slots are executed in the main thread.

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/thread-basics.html